# Workstation 9 Error: Connection activation failed: Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable

Tags: nat, centos6, vmware-workstation

I have tried to get an answer to this from the people at vmware, but have not received any support.

This is a continuation of the problem I had in this post restoring a CentOS 6 Vitual Machine...

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/459939

As I indicated the Guest OS is up and running after I copied over 015.vdk and did the command line linux check disk.  My issue is now the NAT no longer works and I cannot access the outside world from my Guest OS.  This may have something to do with the fact that I am not running it from the original Guest OS, but instead am running it from a new Instance tied to the old virtual disk.

When I run ifconfig and ifup eth3 I get the following output:

[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:F2:F0:F4

```
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000

      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

      Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024
```

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

```
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1

      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0

      RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)
```

[root@localhost ~]# ifup eth3

Error: Connection activation failed: Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable

I have removed all network connection on my Host OS (Windows 7) that were related to the VMWare in hopes it would recreate these connections, but there are now no connections on the HOST related to VMWear.  I have confirmed that the VM has a NAT network adapter set up in the Guest OS's settings. Any input would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue occur because of two reasons:

1#: Your Network Adapter setting issue to check it first remove all your network adapter from device manager and scan to add again, and dont assign static ip set it to obtain auto. repair Network settings and see if these gets ip address. if no IP than is most probably with Vmware Workstation NAT settings.

2#: go to Vmware Workstation--> Edit--> Virtual Network Editor, here you can see different networks which you already created. Remove all Networks here and if you are advance user just delete the NAT network which you are using for your VM.

Now Click on Add Network... Select Any Network Name like VMnet01 or etc than click ok. Now Select Settings which are mentioned below VMnet Information. select NAT than click Connect to host virtual network adapter and than use any Network Setting for your DHCP like 192.168.150.0 and Click Ok. now you have created a New NAT Network.

Now Right Click your Installed VM, go to settings--> Select your Network Adapter, click on Custom:Specific Virtual Network. click ok and start you VM Machine and You are Good to go.